# How to remove defined text (http headers) from a text file

Tags: python

I have a data set of documents containing http headers. I want to go through these documents remove these headers while leaving rest of the text. How can I do that?

```
WARC/1.0
WARC-Type: response
WARC-Date: 2012-02-10T21:58:44Z
WARC-TREC-ID: clueweb12-0000wb-76-38422
WARC-IP-Address: 207.241.148.80
WARC-Payload-Digest: sha1:W6JMWCNM43FDYNW466OADMH2KDGKJCGR
WARC-Target-URI: http://someurl.http
WARC-Record-ID: <urn:uuid:5a783f09-f0d8-4564-8f3a-c0d1ace7177b>
Content-Type: application/http; msgtype=response
Content-Length: 26043

HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Date: Fri, 10 Feb 2012 21:58:45 GMT
Server: Apache
Vary: *
PRAGMA: no-cache
P3P: CP="IDC DSP COR DEVa TAIa OUR BUS UNI"
Cache-Control: max-age=-3600
Expires: Fri, 10 Feb 2012 20:58:45 GMT
Connection: close
Content-Type: text/html
```

Comment: those are HTTP headers, not HTML

Comment: Yes I know, that's why in the question I have used the word "headers". I might have not been able to properly convey the message. I rephrased it.

Comment: You should show how you're getting this document. Usually the HTTP headers are not included in the body of a response.

Comment: @DanielRoseman I got a dataset of such files. They all have such headers.

Comment: So you have a single text file that includes these headers and you want to walk through the text file and remove the headers leaving the rest of the text? Or something else. Your question is very unclear. Please try to describe it as though we have no prior knowledge of what the problem is (because we don't) and tell us as much as we would need to know to understand what you want to do.

Comment: @jwpfox "you want to walk through the text file and remove the headers leaving the rest of the text"
I am trying to do exactly that

Answer (score 1):

This will do what you say you want.
It will leave the original file alone and put the cleaned version into a new file.

```
datafile = 'test1.txt'
outputfile = 'output.txt'

with open(outputfile, encoding='utf-8', mode='w') as outfile:
    with open(datafile, encoding='utf-8', mode='r') as infile:
        foundhdrstart = False

        for line in infile:
            if line.strip() == 'WARC/1.0':
                foundhdrstart = True
            if foundhdrstart is False:
                outfile.write(line)
            if line.strip() == 'Content-Type: text/html':
                foundhdrstart = False
```